# C# problems with HTTPContext.request.params and HTTPContext.request.params.get()

Tags: c#, parameters, httpcontext, missing-data

I hope that someone could help me with the following problem because I'm really lost.

I get a C# `HttpContext` from an ajax javascript call into a C# Handler.

Then, running debug mode with VS I can see that the `context.Request.Params` return the following string:

```
id_affaire=225&Files=%3bT.00000.11-EXE-01-R+1-PL-202-B.dwg%3bT.00000.11-EXE-01-R+1-PL-202-B.dwg&table_colonne=Flexigrid_PanierBordereau&page=1&rp=10&sortname=nom&sortorder=asc&query=&qtype=&ASP.NET_SessionId=o314eh2yjush1pxno2geu42....
```

but doing this: `context.Request.Params.Get("Files")` I get the following string

```
;T.00000.11-EXE-01-R 1-PL-202-B.dwg;T.00000.11-EXE-01-R 1-PL-202-B.dwg
```

The problem is that the character `+` has disappeared...

```
 ;T.00000.11-EXE-01-R 1-PL-202-B.dwg;T.00000.11-EXE-01-R 1-PL-202-B.dwg
```

I'm supposed to get the full name of the file in parameter and the `+` should be in the R+1 string like this:

```
;T.00000.11-EXE-01-R+1-PL-202-B.dwg;T.00000.11-EXE-01-R+1-PL-202-B.dwg
```

Anyone can help me to have the string in params of the httpContext as it has been send (with the missing special char `+`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode the parameters before passing it to the url & decode the pamameters after getting them by context.Request.Params.Get("Files").

You can use:

```
HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode Method (String)
HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode Method (String)
```

Eg.:

**Encode**

```
String MyURL;
MyURL = "http://www.contoso.com/articles.aspx?title=" + Server.UrlEncode("ASP.NET Examples");
```

**Decode**

```
String DecodedString = Server.UrlDecode(EncodedString);
```